# Working with database & architectural issue

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, architecture

I'm developing a web app (not ASP.NET), and I encountered a small architectural problem:

So, i have two classes to work with users.

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    // Other properties...
}

public class Profile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string PhotoUrl { get; set; }

    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public List<PostItem> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

I had to split these classes because there is a feature that allows you to view profile of the certain member, and obviously you don't want to retrieve data from database that contains user's password, name and other private stuff (though it's not displayed in view). So i'm storing this data in different tables: table *Users* contains personal infomation, while table *Profiles* contains public one (it can be viewed by anyone).

But at the same time, in order not to break **Single responsibility principle**, i had to implement *UserRepository* and *ProfileRepository* classes that does some checking, adding and other stuff.

And here they come:

- Issue 1: code that handles user registration is turned into real hell now, i have to check if record with specific username exists in the two different tables by instantiating two repositories.
- Issue 2: Also on the page where you can view public data, there is a need to display latest posts, but here is another problem: i can't store complicated values in one column, so i have to store posts in another table too. It means that i need to implement PostRepository and at the same time property *Posts* in *Profile* class is useless (though i need it to display latest posts in view), because in order to retrieve latest posts you need to look through other table inside *UserRepository*, but it should be handled by *PostRepository*. For example the same goes for comments.

So, this is my *small* problem. Any advices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, taking each item in turn;

1) Its perfectly normal to have the Identity of a user checked through one repository and their permissions to your application stored in another. In fact this is the basic idea behind federated identity. Consider that your might extend your application to allow Identity to be provided by Facebook, but permissions by your own application, and you will see that separating them makes sense.

2) Yes, absolutely. What makes you think that a high volume store like Posts is best served by the same repository that you store a low-change-rate set of data like Permissions in ? One might be in Mongo, the other in Active Directory, with the Identity being OAUTH. You see that since your own the whole application you see these as being unnecessary complexities, whereas they represent good architectural separation.

Identity => not owned by your application. Slow change rate.
Permissions => owned by your application. Slow change rate.
Posts => owned by your application. Fast change rage.

Just looking at those three use-cases, it seems that using different repositories would be a good idea since they have such different profiles. If ultimately your repositories all map to a SQL Server (or other) implementation, then so be it; but by separating these architecturally you can use the best possible underlying implementation.